# Building Masks (0-1 binary image) out of ROIs in Envi Classic?

Tags: envi, masking, extract-by-mask, region

I have the following 701x551 image in Envi with the shown raster ROIs (By pressing `pixel`button of `ROI Tool`dialogue window, I've converted the ROIs into raster format but I have access to ROI vectors eg. polygons if necessary) as training data.

[image]

I want to extract a binary image (a mask) with 701x551 pixels in Envi format in which the pixels inside the ROI are 1 and outside the ROI are 0, so I can use the ROIs as a matrix of 0-1 values and multiply it with my 701x551 data matrix in MATLAB to extract the the training vector for [libsvm tool](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/index.html).

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using the classic GUI of Envi 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: simply go to **Basic Tools > Masking > Build Mask**, select the desired display and then in the options menu of **Mask Definition** Dialog, select `Import ROIs`

[image]

And you'll get the following Mask:

[image]